# Renewing Apache SSL Certificate

Tags: apache, ssl

I have an apache server running on port 443 with an expired SSL certificate. I created a new certificate today and I want to replace it.

I am running a red hat machine. So I went in to /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf and replaced the path to the existing SSL certificate to the new one. 
 After restarting the server, somehow it is still pointing to the old certificate.

Can anyone give me a hand with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be more than one thing going on: there is another install of the `httpd` server and that is the one that is running or there are multiple `.conf` files. I would try a broad answer.

First find the **config** folder for apache:

```
 $ httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
 .......
 ....... 
-D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="run/httpd.pid"
-D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

Now check to see the number of `vhosts` that are defined in any of the .conf files anywhere. And / or you could simply grep for "`SSLCertificateFile`" that is used to specify the certificate and figure out which `vhost` it belongs to and make that update there.

Unless the main `.conf` file points to `.conf` files outside of the `HTTPD_ROOT`, you should be successful.

EDIT 1: Remember to make sure that the pid that you get from the above matches that of the running Apache httpd.

```
$ cat  /etc/httpd/run/httpd.pid
23799
root@devssl1-m1-ap-->/app/workspace/eclipse/rcmtools/ccc/trunk
$ ps -eaf | grep httpd
root     23799     1  0 Mar06 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I believe I have everything right. However when I try to restart to server I get the following warning: [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence.

Comment: This implies that you have more than one virtual host on 443. Open up the config and then check. Your request to 443 is going to the other virtual host on 443.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the configuration file for the vhost you are accessing. Maybe the path is redefined there.